# os.system doesn't work, but command line wokrs

Tags: python, linux, docker, shell, command-line

I have a python file in my docker container and its base is ubuntu.
In that file, i was trying to run an application, for example,
`os.system('./application)`
However, when I checked the docker log, the application cannot find some libraries `(libtbb.so.2)`, but when I execute the
`'./application' on the same directory through docker exec.`
It worked. Also, I found out that if I do `sudo ./application` I was able to generate same error.

I have tried to use subprocess.call, but this method still generate same error.
Is there way that I can un sudo to os.system? or is there way that I can solve this?

Comment: Using `sudo` in a Docker container is rather unusual. You should fix the cause of the library issue instead.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct location? Try using absolute paths.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?